# Why was this question closed, it is clear and has factual answer

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/146235/mac-os-x-certification) was closed as not a real question, but it seems obvious enough? Restated it's asking if Apple offers the equivalent of Sun's Java programming certificates.  The question could be stated a bit more clearly (Apple only, or anyone offering such for iPhone/objective C), but on the whole it doesn't seem like a bad question, it would not be hard at all to anwser in such a way as to cover the possible answers to the question, even without it being editted.

This seems like a good fit to the site to me (unlike SO, where it started), so why was it closed?

Answer (score 4):

The question shows no effort at all, Programmers is not a replacement for a basic web search. The "not a real question" close reason reads as:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

In this case I'd say the question is incomplete, lacking any visible effort and explanation on why the obvious answers aren't enough, and vague and overly broad as Oracle (and not Sun) has a ton of certifications.

It could have also been closed as "not constructive" as it's a request for external resources that doesn't present us with an actual, practical problem to be solved, what we lovingly call a [shopping recommendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: The short and correct answer is "no", which means that he might have taken the effort, but doesn't trust the results.  So I agree with the lack of visible effort, but is that really included in "incomplete"? As for vague, he's asking if they have any, so in a sense vague, but given the answer not really. But if they had a lot of programmer certs, he probably wouldn't be asking.  As for shopping cart, I guess I could see that if people answered with alternative providers, and of course the answer could change.

Comment: @jmoreno How does that answer make the internet a better place? I get where you are coming from, and I do appreciate that you are trying to help, but at the end of the day the answer the OP was looking for can be found with a simple web search. That's not what Programmers is about, or any Stack Exchange site, we are supposed to be the site where you come when you haven't found an answer anywhere else, and you need the help of a bunch of seasoned software developers. As a rule of thumb, if you can find your answer on Google or Wikipedia, the question doesn't belong here.

Comment: @jmoreno You seem to have already formed an opinion, why not contribute an answer? This isn't about convincing me, the community might agree with you...

Comment: you're right, I wasn't thinking enough Meta..

Comment: @YannisRizos: You make it sound like SE sites should be the last resort, which doesn't seem like a good stance.  On SO, I've encountered cases where people advocate SO over FAQs because FAQs aren't maintained by a community and might be out of date or might be more representative of one person's opinion rather than the community at large.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, I am advocating that SE sites should be the last resort, and [I'm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130664/162704) [not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/162704) [alone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128551#128551) [in](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128572#128572) [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128549#128549), minimal research is required.

Answer (score 0):

So, the reason why it was closed has been answered, but since this is Meta, I'll express my response as another answer...

The answer to the question is "No, there isn't".  But Apple doesn't specifically say they don't offer certificates for developers, and are unlikely to ever do so. Likewise for Wikipedia, where an article on a non existent certificate would not fit their site.

Which means that unless the answer changes, a developer looking for a certificate from Apple for Objective-C/iPhone development is not going to find an official answer, at best they are going to find random people who say the answer is "no" or even worse "not that I know of", and they aren't going to be able to weigh how reliable that answer is...and are going to be left wondering if maybe if they just add the right term, would they find the that Apple does, but only ....

SE offers an alternate authority -- someone that has an interest in providing a negative answer, and whose reliability can be at least somewhat weighed, both by their rep and by the fact that it hasn't been contradicted by someone with higher rep.  In short the question is of interest to programmers and because the answer is no, a P.SE answer would be as close to an official answer as there is.

If such a certificate existed, the programmers of SE would know...

Comment: You can find all Apple certificates [here](http://training.apple.com/). If a certificate isn't listed there, they don't offer it, simple as that. You're over thinking this.